# Cycles render changes to Blender render when I open it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on

I was making a project in blender, with cycles render. I saved it but when I reopened it, it changed from cycles render to blender render. It said:[image] Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Maybe you disabled in the meantime the Cycles render addon. Can you manually switch to Cycles?

Comment: No, it only gives me the options Blender render and Blender game... But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cycles is indeed an add-on, as your error message suggests. I don't remember if it's enabled by default or not, but nevertheless it seems to have been disabled.

To enable it:

1. Open up user preferences (*File* -> *User Preferences* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>).
2. Go to the *Add-ons* tab.
3. Click *Render* in the *Categories* list to the left.
4. Make sure the checkbox next to *Render: Cycles Render Engine* is checked.
5. Click the *Save User Settings* button.

[image]